# Flipbook using right footers

Tags: graphics, header-footer, animations

I spent some time looking at similar flip book topics but still cannot produce the intended output. I'm reviewing the FlipBook manual, but the commands I don't understand how to implement yet are:

```
\fbImageB{./Images/Anims/an3/im}{png}{scale=0.25}
```

and

```
\fbImage*{./DIR/PREFIX}{png}{scale=0.2}
```

Ideally there will be 52 different jpg pictures to flip through, placed on the odd pages. So far I've got one image (called pp1.jpg) to appear on the odd pages as intended, but how do I call up the rest? I'm using Writelatex (would this be an issue?). I included two example poems other than my own in the MWE below - thank you community! Any feedback is highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.9in, paperheight=8.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[letterspace=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{flipbook}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\lhead{Author}
\rhead{\thepage}
\chead{}
\lfoot{\bf TITLE}
\rfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox
to\headwidth{\dotfill}\vss}}

\lsstyle

\begin{document}

Frontcover, Preface, pages

\newpage

Contents page

\newpage

% The first flip book image

\fancyfoot[RO]{\begin{picture}(35,10)
\put(0,-68){\includegraphics{pp1.jpg}}
\end{picture}}

\begin{center}

\section*{A Dream Deferred}

What happens to a dream deferred?\\
Does it dry up\\
like a raisin in the sun?\\
Or fester like a sore—\\
And then run?\\
Does it stink like rotten meat?\\
Or crust and sugar over—\\
like a syrupy sweet?

Maybe it just sags\\
like a heavy load.

Or does it explode?

\end{center}

Langston Hughes


\newpage


\begin{center}


\section*{Circus Animal}

Another day\\
Inside this cage

My life broken\\
Into so many pieces

I keep cutting myself\\
Against the bars

\end{center}

E. Ethelbert Miller

\newpage

another poem

\newpage

another poem because we love poetry = )

\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image: <code>Picture 1/52</code>]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! If you can it is better to cut your example down to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) as this makes it much easier for people to help you!

Comment: Is the picture meant to mean something?

Answer (score 1):

With the fancyhdr package you can specify that you want a picture at right foot in odds pages.

The flipbook package will generates a flipbook (inserting images at)

```
\fancyfoot[RO]{                           % Flipbook at right foot in odd pages
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}                % Specify the units
  \begin{picture}(0,0)                    % New picture
    \put(-0.2,-2){                        % Position of the picture
      \fbImageF{./Fig/Flipbook/image_}{png}{width=2cm} % Insert numbered picture in increasing order. Directory: ./Fig/Flipbook. Prefix of all pictures: image_ (in fact image_1, image_2, ...). Extension of the pictures: png. 
     }
 \end{picture}
}
```

The command is:

```
\fbImageF{./DIR/PREFIX}{EXT}{width=WIDTH}
```

with:

- \fbImageF: increasing order of the numbered pictures,
- \fbImageB: decreasing order of the numbered pictures,
- DIR: the path to the pictures,
- PREFIX: the prefix of all pictures (for example: image_1.png, image_2.png, ...),
- EXT: the extension of the picture (for example: jpg, png, ...),
- WIDTH: the width of the picture with units (for example: 1cm).